# How do I use javax.validation (JSR303) on a base class?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I want to use standard javax.validation for properties and my own validation for functional validations. The simplified subclass looks like:

```
public class TestData extends AbstractData {
  @NotNull
  Long id = null;

  @NotNull
  Long value = null;

  public Set<ConstraintViolation<TestData>> validateFunctional() {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<TestData>> violations = new HashSet<>();
    if ( id < 42 || value > 4711 ) {
      //--- here comes another question: how do I create a constraint violation?
     }
     return violations;
  }
}
```

This is the base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractData {
  public Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> validate() {
    //--- First validate single properties
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = validator.validate( this );
  }
  //--- Single props OK => validate functional
  if ( violations.isEmpty()) {
     violations.add( validateFunctional());
  }
  return violations;
}
```

Gives the error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<ConstraintViolation<AbstractData>> to Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>

Comment: There is no way for the compiler to infer the generic type the way you did it.

Comment: You are right. The compiler cannot convert from AbstractData to ?. But how can I get rid of this pseudo-type-safety? It seems to me, that the interface Validator.validate is just badly designed. Or I just don't get it ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be what you are looking for:

```
public abstract class AbstractData<T> {

  abstract T getObj();

  public Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> isValid(){
    //do your custom validations if needed
    return Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
            .getValidator().validate(getObj());
  }
}
```

POJO to be validated:

```
public class Bar extends AbstractData<Bar> {
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Long value;

    @CustomConstraint
    private Long customConstraint;

    @Override
    public Bar getObj() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then simply call `bar.isValid()`.

**EDIT:**

Regarding your question about a custom constraint, you can do it like this:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomConstraint.CustomConstraintValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CustomConstraint {

    String message() default "Invalid value";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class CustomConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomConstraint, Long> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(CustomConstraint customConstraint) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Long obj, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

            if (obj < 10)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, if I annotate a Long field with `@CustomConstraint` and pass the value lower than 10 or null, the validator will return an error, otherwise it won't. The validation itself is useless in the example, I just put up something to serve as a snippet for you to build yours.

Comment: Interesting approach. But the custom validations are in the subclasses, not in the base class. To overcome the really weird generics in validator.validate, your solution is to give the subclass as a generic parameter to its own base class which also requires the method "abstract T getObj()" which just returns "this". I really hope that this JSR gets an update which makes it usable. I'm not looking for a custom validator but instead for some code to 'easily' create a constraint violation which I can add to the set of violations.

Comment: I think maybe you are misunderstanding the whole generics here, because I don't see anything wrong with how it is implemented by the `validate()`.

Comment: Its not wrong. Its only needlessly complicated without any benefits. The first paramater to validate() is the bean to validate. So it knows the class. There is no need for this pseudo type safety. Your solution suggested to add a getter into the base class just to conform to this.